# Difference between this.form and document.forms

Tags: javascript, forms, this, document

Is there a difference between `this.form` and `document.forms (document["forms"])` or, are they similar?

Here is the code I wrote to test the difference.

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="haha" id="myForm" value="laughable" onclick="alert(this.form.haha.value)" />
</form>

alert(document.forms.myForm.haha.value);
```

They both result in the same thing.

Comment: I tried writing some code but in the way that I wrote it they work very similar to each other.

Comment: MDN has a [good article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) about the this keyword, that might give you some additional insights.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this.form` will give you the form of the form element.  (`this` is the form element)

> The containing form element, if this element is in a form.

`document.forms` will give you all the forms in the document (if it's supported!)

> forms returns a collection (an HTMLCollection ) of the form elements within the current document.

Better use `document.getElementById(id)`

```
var form = document.getElementById(formId);
```

Comment: Unless `this` happens to mean some completely other thing.

Answer (score 0):

`this.form` will return the form property of this, as noted above whatever `"this"` is.

`"this"` could be anything, eg. a div, so possibly doesn't have a form property.

If `"this"` happens to refer to document, then `this.form` will return exactly the same thing as `document.form`. But otherwise, don't count on it.