# HTML/PHP Form - Don't refresh on change

Tags: jquery, html, forms, refresh, onchange

I have the below HTML-form and PHP-queries, which display database entries based on the dropdown-selection. In general, the queries and the forms are working, but I would like to prevent the whole webpage from refreshing, but still get the data displayed.

I am aware the culprit is the `onchange="this.form.submit();"`
However, I could not get it to work with jquery.1.8.3.min. The directory/path of the jquery is `src="js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js"`

This is the full code of my HTML-form and PHP-queries. Many thanks in advance for your support.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['gebiet1'])){
    $selected_val = $_POST['gebiet1'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
    echo "Sie haben " .$selected_val." selektiert.";  // Displaying Selected Value
}
?>

<?php
require_once ('config.php');
$db = mysqli_connect (
                     MYSQL_HOST, 
                     MYSQL_BENUTZER, 
                     MYSQL_KENNWORT, 
                     MYSQL_DATENBANK
                    );
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
    <div id="select">
    <select name="gebiet1" onchange="this.form.submit();">

<?php
$gebietausgabe = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT DISTINCT Gebiet FROM kernfragen");
while ($row = $gebietausgabe->fetch_assoc())
{

  echo '<option value="' . $row['Gebiet'] . '">' . $row['Gebiet'] . '</option>';
}

?>

    </select>
    </div>
</form>

<?php        
if(isset($_POST['gebiet1'])){
$ergebnis = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT idKernfragen, Kernfrage FROM kernfragen WHERE Gebiet='".$selected_val."'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($ergebnis))
{
  echo $row->idKernfragen;
  echo '.) ';
  echo $row->Kernfrage;
  print "<br>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, many thanks for looking at the topic and responding. I cannot see how my question is related to the link you posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042214/difference-between-this-form-and-document-forms I cannot find the solution what should be changed around the onchange="this.form.submit()" statement.

Comment: I was expecting you to check out the accepted answer, where it shows the form submission. I will remove the close vote.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid a complete reload of the page you need to avoid a submit of the form as this will do a load of the action url.

for this kinds of modifying only parts of a page you need [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)) which requires a special javascritp to fire the request and exchange the content and also a server-script which returns only the part you need to exchange (no whole html page with head, css, ...)

Comment: Hi Bernd, many thanks. Using Ajax, how do I refer to the form as the name is <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST"> ?

Comment: just walk your DOM. if it's the only form in the page you can use `document.form` otherwise you can use `this.form` or any selector to identify the input fields to get their value. don't forget to `return false` at the end of your javascript, otherwise the action may be executed with a page reload too

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. This is not working yet - any advice? Many thanks in advance. <script type ="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.8.3.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function () {

        $(document.form).on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function () {
              alert('form was submitted');
            }
          });

        });

      });
    </script>